# Multiple Javascript If / Else Statements not working, only last one is executing

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on multiple javascript if/else statements and they don't seem to be working. Only the Last part "Currently enrolled" is working. I am looking to get both the Yes and currently enrolled statements to work when a user selects from the drop down. The code I have is below:

```
function testBSN() {

if (document.getElementById('BSN').value == 'Yes') {
   document.getElementById('BSNQuestion'}.style.display = 'table-row';


} else {
   document.getElementById('BSNQuestion').style.display = 'none';
}   

if (document.getElementById('BSN').value == 'Yes') {
    document.getElementById('NSG_Grad_Yr').style.display = 'block';

} else {
   document.getElementById('NSG_Grad_Yr').style.display = 'none';
}   

if (document.getElementById('BSN').value == 'Yes') {
   document.getElementById('Est_NSG_School').style.display = 'block';

} else {
    document.getElementById('Est_NSG_School').style.display = 'none';
}   

if (document.getElementById('BSN').value == 'Currently Enrolled') {
   document.getElementById('BSNQuestion').style.display = 'table-row';


} else {
   document.getElementById('BSNQuestion').style.display = 'none';
}   

if (document.getElementById('BSN').value == 'Currently Enrolled') {
    document.getElementById('NSG_Grad_Yr').style.display = 'block';

} else {
   document.getElementById('NSG_Grad_Yr').style.display = 'none';
}   

if (document.getElementById('BSN').value == 'Currently Enrolled') {
   document.getElementById('Est_NSG_School').style.display = 'block';

    } else {
        document.getElementById('Est_NSG_School').style.display = 'none';
    }   
    }   


</script>
```

And here is the HTML for the section:

```
           <td style="padding-bottom: 10px" valign="top">  
                              <select name="BSN" size="1" id="BSN"     onclick='testBSN()'>
                                <option value="">Please Select</option>
                                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                                <option value="No">No</option>
                                <option value="Currently Enrolled">Currently Enrolled</option>
                          </select></td>
                          </tr>

                        <tr id="BSNQuestion" style="background-color: #0082c8; display:none">
                          <td valign="top" ><span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF;">Year of graduation?</span></td>
                          <td valign="top" >&nbsp;</td>
                          <td valign="top"><span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF;">From what school?</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td valign="top">  <select style="display:none" name="NSG_Grad_Yr" id="NSG_Grad_Yr">

                <option value="N/A">Please Select</option>


                <option value="1950">1950</option>
                <option value="1951">1951</option>
                <option value="1952">1952</option>
                <option value="1953">1953</option>
                <option value="1954">1954</option>
                <option value="1955">1955</option>

              </select></td>
                          <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                          <td style="padding-bottom: 10px" valign="top"><input style="display:none" type="text" name="Est_NSG_School" id="Est_NSG_School" size="32" /></td>
                          </tr>
```

Comment: why don't you combined a lot of the statements with the same `if` and `else` conditions together?

Comment: tried that but i still received the same result so I tried to separte to see if I could find the error.

Comment: How do you know the if/else are failing? Throw in some console logs for the element values and see exactly what they are.

Comment: Replace `<select name="BSN"` by `<select id="BSN"`. Forget about the `name` attribute —it’s useless.

Comment: You can write the entire logic in 4-5 lines

Comment: Also, in your first statement you’ve got `('BSNQuestion'}`. Replace that curly bracket `}` by a normal round one: `)`. And by the way: separating if statements and repeating code won’t make errors easier to find — quite the contrary.

Comment: This question is presented in a way that is somewhat hard to read but I don't see why it's getting so downvoted. Could you be clearer on what is "not working"?

Comment: Thank you, I replaced the bracket but the last part of the if statements are only working. If someone could give me an example of how to combine into 4-5 lines, I would be happy to do that, but I am new to this..

Comment: Did you replace `name` by `id` yet?

Comment: When i execute the code, the only part that is working is the "Currently Enrolled" section of if statements. The "Yes" part of the if statements won't even execute

Comment: @Xufox it has both name and id `<select name="BSN" size="1" id="BSN"`

Comment: @ThisClark Oh, I didn’t see it, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your poor indentation of code made this question very difficult to read and troubleshoot. I had to not only recreate the solution, but I also had to fix your invalid HTML. All of that was necessary before I recognized your problem is simply this ---

Your first IF condition does work....

```
if (document.getElementById('BSN').value === 'Yes') {
  document.getElementById('BSNQuestion').style.display = 'table-row';
  document.getElementById('NSG_Grad_Yr').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('Est_NSG_School').style.display = 'block';
} else {
  document.getElementById('BSNQuestion').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('NSG_Grad_Yr').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('Est_NSG_School').style.display = 'none';
}
```

... but its effects are later reversed by this condition:

```
if (document.getElementById('BSN').value === 'Currently Enrolled') {
  document.getElementById('BSNQuestion').style.display = 'table-row';
  document.getElementById('NSG_Grad_Yr').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('Est_NSG_School').style.display = 'block';

} else {
  document.getElementById('BSNQuestion').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('NSG_Grad_Yr').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('Est_NSG_School').style.display = 'none';
}
```

**Suppose value == 'Yes' then you continue to check value == 'Currently Enrolled'. Since value was not 'Currently Enrolled' (since we know it was 'Yes') you still trigger the else condition that hides the display (even though you want it to show for 'Yes').**

To fix, do this:

```
var answer = document.getElementById('BSN').value;
if (answer === 'Yes' || answer === 'Currently Enrolled') {
  document.getElementById('BSNQuestion').style.display = 'table-row';
  document.getElementById('NSG_Grad_Yr').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('Est_NSG_School').style.display = 'block';
} else {
  document.getElementById('BSNQuestion').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('NSG_Grad_Yr').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('Est_NSG_School').style.display = 'none';
}
```

[Fiddle >](http://jsfiddle.net/Xorat/wh6nxx2e/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an else if.

```
function abc() {
 if (condition1) {
  // something happens
 } else if (condition2) {
  // something else happens
 } else {
  // runs if the if and else if do not execute
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think onclick='testBSN()' is the one creating problem. try onchange='testBSN()'